# Tangent line problem using differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this question in my work and I tried many things but I do not know how to do it, however I believe differential equations should be used.

The problem:
 Find an equation of the curve which contains the point (−5,−9)
(5,9)and is such for any point P which is on the curve and not on the x-axis, the x-intercept of the normal line to the curve at P is 5 units to the left of P.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest drawing a diagram. Plot a point (x,y), the projection onto the x axis (x,0), and the point where the normal line hits the x axis (x+5,0). This triangle is similar to the triangle which represents the slope of the line. Once you find the differential equation, the solution should follow. If you need any more help, just ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the normal in $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is

$$\tag{1}y-f(x_0)=-\tfrac{1}{f'(x_0)}(x-x_0).$$

This normal intersects the $x$ axis in a point $(x_1,0)$, with

$$\tag{2}0-f(x_0)=-\tfrac{1}{f'(x_0)}(x_1-x_0)$$

With the given constraint $x_1-x_0=-5$, (2) becomes

$$\tag{3}f(x_0)f'(x_0)=-5$$

or, changing all instances of $x_0$ into $x$:

$$\tag{4}2f(x)f'(x)=-10$$

This differential equation is easily integrable into :

$$\tag{5}f(x)^2=-10x+b \ \ \ \iff \ \ \ \begin{cases}f(x)&=&\sqrt{-10x+131}\\ f(x)&=&-\sqrt{-10x+31}\end{cases}$$

the constants $131$ and $31$ being chosen in such a way that the curves passes through points $(5,9)$ and $(-5,-9)$.

The domain of validity of the first (resp. 2nd) function is $I_1=(-\infty,13.1)$ (resp.  $I_2=(-\infty,3.1)$ ). Thus a choice has to be made for $x \in I_2$ between one of the 2 functions.